# jumping in a game

Tags: javascript, math, physics, gravity

I'm making a 2d side scroller and for the life of me I can't get jumping to work. This is how I'm doing moving left and right:

```
for(var i = 0; i < time; i++)
     newVelocityX = (oldVelocityX + accelerationX) * frictionX;
```

then to update my player position I do

> positionX = oldPositionX + newVelocityX;

This works great, and the variable "time" just has the amount of ms it's been since I last ran the function. Friction works great and I'm happy it's all good in the X direction. This is what I have in the Y direction:

```
for(var i = 0; i < time; i++) {
    accelerationY += gravityAccelerationY;
    newVelocityY = oldVelocityY + accelerationY;
}
```

The object falls down due to gravity just fine. If I set a negative accelerationY when the user hits the up arrow then I can even make the player jump, but on a fast computer they jump very high, and on an old computer they jump very low. I'm not sure how to fix this, I thought I already was accounting for this by putting it in the foor loop like I did.

Comment: It sounds as though there were a significant interval between the expiry of an old timer and the starting of a new one.  Of course, on a slow computer, such an interval would be longer.  But this is just a thought: if irrelevant, please disregard.  Good luck.

Comment: Could we see some more code? Such as the main game loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to do several things to change your code to work properly. There are numerous bugs/performance hits in the code you posted.

Here is some code to do the basics of the game.

Sample code for the jumping:

```
if (jump) {
    velocityY = -jumpHeightSquared; // assuming positive Y is downward, and you are jumping upward
}
velocityY += gravityAccelerationY * time;
positionY += velocityY * time;
if (positionY > 0) {
    positionY = 0; // assuming the ground is at height 0
    velocityY = 0;
}
```

Sample code for moving sideways:

```
velocityX += accelerationX * time;
velocityX *= Math.pow(frictionX, time);
positionX += velocityX * time;
```

Some comments on the code:

The velocity and position variables need to keep their values in between frames (I'm assuming you've got that figured out).

gravityAccelerationY and frictionX are constant values, unless gravity or friction changes.

Where I replaced your for loops with `* time`, using a single multiplication will be faster than a loop. The only difference would be at low frame rates, or high rates of acceleration, where the acceleration would seem to be 'sped up' from what it should be. You shouldn't have problems with that though.